# Pandoc generated table: decimal alignment

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

I'm having a hard time trying to get Pandoc to generate a table with properly aligned decimal points. Looks like out of the box this isn't supported.

If I have a simple markdown table with one column:

```
|  6.5 | 
|  8.5 | 
|  6   | 
| 11   | 
| 14   |
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve proper decimal alignment without hand-tweaking the TeX template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as of 2015 the [internal Pandoc representation of table alignments](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-types/blob/master/Text/Pandoc/Definition.hs#L143) includes only left, right, center and default. So you'll have to tweak your TeX template or if you're targeting only TeX output, you can write [inline-Tex](http://pandoc.org/README.html#raw-tex).